# Enum Filtering: include value at index + 1

Tags: list, elixir

I am trying to parse unix-style flags from an `args` list, i.e.:

```
args = ["hello", "-f", "val", "-u", "valtwo"]
# Desired outcome: [{"-f", "val"}, {"-u", "valtwo"}]
```

I've managed to extract the flags with the following regex:

```
args
|> Enum.filter(fn arg -> Regex.match?(~r/^-{1,2}\w+/, arg) end)
# ["-f", "-u"]
```

However, in order to get the **values** that correspond to these keys, I need to get the value of args at the next index.

I've considered transforming the array using `Enum.chunk_every(2)` (discarding the first element, `"hello"`), but that's not sufficiently flexible, since that will break on the following:

```
["hello", "-f", "val", "secondvalforf", "-u", "valtwo"]
# Achieved outcome: [{"-f", "val"}, {"secondvalforf", "-u"}, {"valtwo"}]
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reduce/3) is your friend here.

```rb
args = ~w|hello -f val foo -u valtwo|
#⇒ ["hello", "-f", "val", "foo", "-u", "valtwo"]

Enum.reduce(args, [], fn 
  <<?-, _>> = key, args -> [{key, []} | args]
  _, [] -> [] # skip plain arguments
  arg, [{key, last} | rest] -> [{key, last ++ [arg]} | rest]
end)
#⇒ [{"-u", ["valtwo"]}, {"-f", ["val", "foo"]}]
```

Call [`Enum.reverse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#reverse/1) on the result to preserve the order of keys (`reduce` *prepends* new elements to the accumulator to avoid creating many subsequent linked lists down the road.)